# Saving jwt token in cookie in laravel

Tags: laravel, cookies, jwt

When I create a jwt token in my laravel and I save it in the cookie it become hashed again I guess and I can not retrieve my jwt token from the cookie again.

for example this is my original token :

```
$token = eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTc4MDkzNDEsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsInVybCI6InRlc3QuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk3OTA5MzQxLCJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0In0.I8p0x5DM8wXruucgkp1W7b4XbHEPEyJkQn2b71e9XTA
```

which its payload is :

```
$payload = [
        'iat' => time(),
        'email' => "test@test.com", 
        'url'=>"test.com", 
        'exp' => time() + 100000,
        'iss' =>"test",
    ];
```

I save it in laravel cookie with this command:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::queue("jwt_token", $token, 60);
```

and when I retrieve the cookie, the value is something else which can not be decoded.

Note: the token is going to be used from another application in the same domain which is not laravel based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was in the EncryptCookies middleware. I put my jwt_token in the $except property of the class and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I use this got the exact same token string back.

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

$value = Cookie::get('jwt_token');
```

You may change your token like this:

```php
$token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE1OTc4MDkzNDEsImVtYWlsIjoidGVzdEB0ZXN0LmNvbSIsInVybCI6InRlc3QuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk3OTA5MzQxLCJpc3MiOiJ0ZXN0In0.I8p0x5DM8wXruucgkp1W7b4XbHEPEyJkQn2b71e9XTA';
```

Comment: The problem is that the token is going to be used from another application in the same domain which is not laravel based.